# Структура js приложения

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, проектирование

Придумал структуру, думаю, что она не верная и запутанная.

**Задача:** Нужно сделать вид для 2 групп пользователей, допустим `User` и `Admin`.

Есть форма, которая будит дополняться в случае, если пришла нужная нам группа.
3 файла: основной (1), стандартная форма (2), модифицированная форма (3).

Моя логика:

1. Проверка (для одной группы 1 файл не доступен), т.е. в 1-ом случай мы не досчитаемся 1 объекта. (`try catch`). Если файл есть - поднимаем объект. (поднимаемый файл наследует стандартную форму и расширяет ее).
2. В стандартной форме, т.е. при инициализации объекта, мы проверяем, делать ли модификацию. Если да, то мы в объекте стандартной формы тянем объект модификаций, который, в свою очередь, наследует стандартную форму.

```js
$(function() {
    var modif;
    try{
        modif = new modifForm();
    }catch(e){
        modif = false;
    }
 var app  = new defaultViewForm(modif)
}

// дефаулт форма
var default = {};
function defaultViewForm(modif) {
 var me = {};
 if(modif){
  me = modif;
 }
    me.test = default.test ,
    me.test = default.test2 
    return me;
}
default.test = function(){
    console.log('default test');
}
default.test2 = function(){
    console.log('default test2');
}
// мод  форма 
var mod = {};
function modViewForm() {
    var me = defaultViewForm.extend; // расширили 
    me.test = default.test2 // переопределили метод
    return me;
}
mod.test = function(){
    console.log('default test2');
  
}
```

Понимаю, что решение никуда не годится, но по другому не понимаю как  реализовать. Подскажите, как сделать красивой данную задачу?

Comment: Вы видите тут ООП? Я нет. Посмотрите на паттерны MVC/MVP/MVVM и сделайте как там описано. И архитектура сразу станет лучше.

Comment: Исправляйте орфографические ошибки, иначе вопрос заблокируют.

Comment: отправить посмотреть .Спасибо  на досуге обязтельно посмотрю. до ооп тут не хватает  2 фаила  тобиш еше код. а это не нужно

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее что в итоге должно получиться?какими средствами пользуетесь? что такое вид? что содержится в ваших файлах?

Comment: В фаилах будут шаблоны формы .   в итоге в зависимости от пользоветоя быть выстраиваться вид ( т е отрисовка  html )
Нужен  ооп подход их  много на  js  хочеться выбрать  болие правильный